# Asset management from console application, Yii

Tags: php, command-line, yii, console-application, assets

**How to access the images published as assests using Yii assets manager from console applications?**

I am sending newsletters using `commands` in Yii( console application ). I could not use the images published as assests in my mail template.

I am having the actual images inside `protected/assets/images/` folder. When i publish them using `asset manager`, they will be available at `root/assets/6f3434/images/` folder.

Usually my code to access an image in Yii's web application would be

`<img src="<?php echo $this->assetBase ?>/images/a.png" />` where `$this->assetBase` referrs the url of the published foler, in this case `root/assets/6f3434`.

The same is not working if i run the code from console application.

Answer (score 1):

You did not explain what exactly is not working. So here's just a general guideline.

You have to configure an `assetManager` component in your console application. And you need to tweak some settings so that you end up with the same asset paths. You should add something like this to your `console.php`:

```
<?php
  'aliases' => array(
      'webroot' => realpath(__DIR_.'/../..'),
  ),
  'components' => array(
      'assetManager'=>array(
          'class'     =>'CAssetManager',
          'basePath'  =>realpath(__DIR__.'/../../assets'),
          'baseUrl'   =>'/assets',
      ),
      'request' => array(
          'baseUrl' => '',
      ),
  ),
      //...
```

Comment: Let me try this solution, thank you!. Now i am using request component & getBaseUrl() function to point the resources directly instead of assets folder.